# EE 2.5.5 channel issues

Tags: channel, error, fields

My EE install are having issues with channel fields.
Normally, when changing field "Type", you get different options.

But in my install, no matter what I set the "Type" field to, I get none options other than the standard "Field settings".

Example: setting "Type" to Assets, should give me lots of Assets options (thumbnail size, folders to upload/select images from etc.). But I get none. Same applies no matter what "Type" I select. I have no clue why.

Anyone know where to start? This is on a clean install with just a few things set up.

Regards
Kristoffer

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your Theme directory may not have been uploaded correctly. Try reuploading it. Also, make sure the jQuery module is installed on the Modules page.

Comment: I found the error. Disabling Channel Images 5.4.2 fixed the problem. Now I'm able to see all the "Field options" again for each field type. Channel Images somehow breaks the whole setup. Strange. Anyone else experiencing this problem with EE? I have CE Image also installed. Could that be the cause of the errors? :)

Comment: I'd suggest reloading all the Channel Images files as well. Perhaps the theme directory didn't get uploaded or part of it is corrupted.